# How to preselect the options of a multiple select? (html + php)

Tags: php, jquery, html, multiple-select

Is it possible to preselect some options of a multiselectbox that won't be deselected by adding a new option select?

I now have a normal multiple selectbox, which options will be preselected by PHP:

```
<select name="selectbox" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B" selected>B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D" selected>D</option>
</select>
```

When I click at option A, option B and D will be deselected and A will be selected.
I'd like to only deselect an item when someone clicks at an already selected option.
When someone clicks at an option which is not yet selected, it has to be added to the already selected items.

What is the best way to do that? Or isn't that possible?

Comment: yes it is possible you can use JQUERY and simply see what values are :selected.

Comment: Or just hold the ctrl key when you click the new option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy with javascript (jQuery), like this:

```
$('select[name=selectbox]').on('mousedown','option',function(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).is(':selected') );
});
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/fe193/1)

Comment: It won't work :) you should use selected instead of checked :)

Comment: Yep, you forget to change also :checked :). Change if ($(this).is(':checked') ) { to if ($(this).is(':selected') ) {

Comment: Thanks I forgot to change that.

Comment: Also why have two preventDefault() ? Just move it to the first line of the function :)

Comment: After trying this out, it was needed to use `mousedown` instead of `click` event. I've updated my answer with this and posted a fiddle example.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but when you try to use "onblur" at the select itself it won't. Luckily "onchange" works perfectly!